# passing pointer to function corrupts pointer

Tags: c, pointers, struct

I'm passing a pointer to a typedef struct to a function that is suppose to set up the typedef struct for use. The struct is already malloced before it is passed to the function. Upon accessing the struct within the function I receive EXC_BAD_ACCESS. The thing I don't understand is, the value of the typedef struct called pool is valid in the previous function, but as soon as it's passed it's not valid. This can be seen in the backtrace below. While researching the problem I've seen similar problems but those were due to passing a copy of the variable to the function instead of a pointer, or because the variable was a local variable and it went out of scope when the function exited. I don't believe these are the problems because the function that declared and malloced pool has not exited yet, and I am passing a pointer to pool not a copy of pool. So how come pool becomes NULL after passing it to initNamePool?

Backtrace, here you can see that pool was valid in "initResourcePool" and "initPools" but not "initNamePool"

```
(lldb) thread backtrace
* thread #1: tid = 0x53998, 0x000000010000325b sysfuzz`initNamePool(pool=0x0000000000000000) + 27 at namePool.c:201, queue = 'com.apple.main-thread', stop reason = EXC_BAD_ACCESS (code=1, address=0x4020)
  * frame #0: 0x000000010000325b sysfuzz`initNamePool(pool=0x0000000000000000) + 27 at namePool.c:201
    frame #1: 0x0000000100002cf5 sysfuzz`initPools(pool=0x00000001003eafe0) + 37 at pool.c:51
    frame #2: 0x0000000100002c80 sysfuzz`initResourcePool(pool=0x00000001003eafe0) + 48 at pool.c:87
    frame #3: 0x0000000100001830 sysfuzz`initSysFuzz(data=0x00000001003d4fd0) + 48 at interactor.c:19
    frame #4: 0x00000001000017ba sysfuzz`initAndRunSysFuzz + 58 at interactor.c:103
    frame #5: 0x0000000100001599 sysfuzz`main + 25 at start.c:12
    frame #6: 0x00007fff956395c9 libdyld.dylib`start + 1
    frame #7: 0x00007fff956395c9 libdyld.dylib`start + 1
```

The Definition of data->pool->nPool and getDirName

```
static int getDirName(char **dir, namePool *pool)
{
    poolArgs *args;

    args = (poolArgs *) malloc(sizeof(poolArgs));
    if(args == NULL)
    {
        return -1;
    }

    launchSynch(pool->serialQueue, gdn, &args);

    dir = args->dir;

    free(args);

    return 0;
}

typedef struct namePool namePool;

struct namePool
{
    char *fileNameIndex[1025];
    char *dirNameIndex[1025];
    queue serialQueue;

    int (*getFileName)(char **, namePool *);
    int (*getDirName)(char **, namePool *);
    int (*fillPool)(namePool *);
    int (*drainPool)(namePool *);
    bool isPoolDrained;
};
```

Here we declare data which is a typedef struct that holds pool. Both get malloced in "initFuzzData".

```
int initAndRunSysFuzz()
{
    /* Declarations. */
    int rtrn;
    fuzzData *data;

    data = initFuzzData();
    if(data == NULL)
    {
        return -1;
    }

    rtrn = initSysFuzz(data);
    if(rtrn < 0)
    {
        cleanUpFuzzData(data);
        return -1;
    }

    ...
}

fuzzData *initFuzzData()
{
    fuzzData *data;

    data = (fuzzData *) malloc(sizeof(fuzzData));
    if(data == NULL)
    {
        return NULL;
    }

    data->pool = (resourcePool *) malloc(sizeof(resourcePool));
    if(data->pool == NULL)
    {
        return NULL;
    }

    data->pool->nPool = (namePool *) malloc(sizeof(namePool));
    if(data->pool->nPool == NULL)
    {
        return NULL;
    }

    ...
}
```

After we malloc data and data->pool and we pass data to "initSysFuzz"

```
static int initSysFuzz(fuzzData *data)
{

    int rtrn;

    rtrn = initResourcePool(data->pool);
    if(rtrn < 0)
    {
        return -1;
    }

    ...
}
```

"initSysFuzz" calls "initResourcePool"

```
int initResourcePool(resourcePool *pool)
{

    int rtrn;

    rtrn = initPools(pool);
    if(rtrn < 0)
    {
        printf("Can't Init Pools\n");
        return -1;
    }
    ...
}
```

Which in turn calls "initPools"

```
static int initPools(resourcePool *pool)
{
    int rtrn;

    rtrn = initNamePool(pool->nPool);
    if(rtrn < 0)
    {
        printf("Can't init name pool\n");
        return -1;
    }

    ....
}
```

And here is where it crashes, on the first line of "initNamePool", pool->getDirName = &getDirName; .

```
int initNamePool(namePool *pool)
{
    pool->getDirName = &getDirName;

...

}
```

Comment: You're passing `pool->nPool` to `initNamePool`, but you never allocated anything for that pointer. Show us where in your code `pool->nPool = ....` is done, because I don't see it.

Comment: I did malloc pool->nPool it just got left out of the question on accident, it's malloced right after data->pool in initFuzzData.

Comment: Try to print adresses of variables after allocation, and just before and after (or inside function) function call. Maybe this will clarify situation.

Comment: thanks I found it by printing the addresses, I had malloced pool twice in initFuzzData.

Comment: a pointer is NEVER less than 0,  it is an unsigned value and should be treated as such.  NULL is defined as a pointer to 0, NOT as some negative number.

Comment: the returned value from any of the malloc family of functions should (for several reasons) not be cast.

Answer (score 1):

I found it by printing the addresses, I had malloced pool twice in initFuzzData. – 2trill2spill